# Why doesn't checking out in TFS 2010 give me write permissions? It causes an exception in my project at the target of invocation

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I just moved my code from subversion to TFS.

When I get latest version, I understand that I can't get write permissions.

However, when I check out and choose the option to take the exclusive lock, a check mark appears next to my files and I am able to edit them.

When I look in Windows explorer, however, some files are still marked "read only."

This becomes a problem when I try and run my application.  For some reason, not having write permissions to everything gives me an exception at the target of invocation message (its a wpf project).

When I run the files out of version control, everything is fine.  When I run the version under TFS, I get that exception--even when I've exclusively checked the files out.

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like quite a bit of confusion here. So i have a number of questions:

1. Did you specifically check out the files that are still marked "read only"?  Or did you just check out other files which may be related to the ones marked "read only".
2. Did you use the Source Control window or the Solution Explorer when performing the checkout command?  Did you select specific files or just the top level project file?
3. Are the files actually part of the project? or are they simply in the same folder but still under source control?
4. What exact error message are you getting?
5. What files are the problem?  In other words have you checked in the compiled binaries from the BIN or OBJ folders?

Answer (score 0):

TFS terminology is a little different than SVN.

"Get" represents an update in SVN terms.

"Checkin" commits your changes and both "Checkin" and "Checkout" are responsible for managing file locks.

"Checkin" releases the locks.

"Checkout" requests the locks.

There are 3 types of locking you can use or none at all.  I would opt for using None as it's likely to cause the least issues, many of which can be resolved during a merge and a little bit of communication.